# IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for rx.Observable RxJava, Retrofit2

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am getting the above error while calling the rest api. I am using both retrofit2 and RxJava.

### ServiceFactory.java

```
public class ServiceFactory {
public static <T> T createRetrofitService(final Class<T> clazz, final String endpoint){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(endpoint)
            //.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

            .build();

    T service = retrofit.create(clazz);
    return service;
}
```

}

### MovieService.java

```
public interface MovieService{
//public final String API_KEY = "<apikey>";
public final String SERVICE_END = "https://api.mymovies.org/3/";
@GET("movie/{movieId}??api_key=xyz")
Observable<Response<Movies>> getMovies(@Field("movieId") int movieId);
```

}

## Inside MainActivity

```
      MovieService   tmdbService = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(MovieService.class, MovieService.SERVICE_END);
    Observable<Response<Movies>> responseObservable = tmdbService.getMovies(400);
    responseObservable .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<Movies>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<Movies> moviesResponse) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Be sure to add `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'` or whatever version you are using to your dependencies, and then configure retrofit with that converter:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(endpoint)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

**Updated**

`RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` was renamed to [RxJava2CallAdapterFactory](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.java). Changed the snipped above.

Comment: Yes I did that and now am getting another error in the addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory)

Comment: ok. Please update your question with the full stack trace and fix the spacing issue on your snipet

Comment: Adapter factory is now renamed to RxJava2CallAdapterFactory, so use .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())

Comment: @ekrem-kenter Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

For RxJava2 Use `compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'`

.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())

For more information on usage https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter

Comment: is now deprecated

Answer (score 14):

you should have to use all **Rx** dependency of latest version , here i am using version **2** (like **rxjava2**)

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
```

[image]

And add one more thing :

```
addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
```

in Retrofit Api client
like :

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

From the said Github project page:

> Blockquote
>   This is now DEPRECATED!
>   Retrofit 2.2 and newer have a first-party call adapter for RxJava 2: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

now you just need to include in your app/build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:latest.version'
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was enough to replace

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
```

with

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
```