# How to resolve Could not locate call adapter for retrofit2.Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody>

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am investigating `Retrofit2` in my Android Application.

My gradle.build resembles:-

```
retrofit2Version = "2.4.0"
rxAndroidVersion = "2.0.2"
rxJavaVersion = "2.1.12"
okhttp3Version = "3.10.0"

implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3Version"

implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2Version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit2Version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit2Version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:$retrofit2Version"

implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
```

I have three versions of the same `@GET` method

```
@Headers("accept: */*")
@GET("experiment")
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> getObservableExperiment(@Header("Authorization") @NonNull final String authenticationToken, @Query("active") @NonNull final Boolean isActive);

@Headers("accept: */*")
@GET("experiment")
Call<ResponseBody> getExperiment(@Header("Authorization") @NonNull final String authenticationToken, @Query("active") @NonNull final Boolean isActive);

@Headers("accept: */*")
@GET("experiment")
Response<ResponseBody> getWrappedExperiment(@Header("Authorization") @NonNull final String authenticationToken, @Query("active") @NonNull final Boolean isActive);
```

Both the `getObservableExperiment()` and `getExperiment()` work OK

however the `getWrappedExperiment()` fails with:-

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for retrofit2.Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody>.
      Tried:
       * retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
       * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:241)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:205)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:238)
```

Is there a call adapter for `retrofit2.Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody>`?
What have I over looked?

Comment: Did you check this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35233161/5180017) or this Retrofit related [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2028) raised in Github?

Comment: @Shashanth, I did see that question (and others just like it) and the GitHub issue, however they are specifically related to RxJava (if I am not mistaken?) and my issue is with a GET call that does not employ RxJava, so how would they assist me?

Comment: Try using `Call<ResponseBody> getWrappedExperiment(...)` instead of `Response<ResponseBody> getWrappedExperiment(...)`. Not sure why you are using `Response` instead of `Call`.

Comment: If possible post the code which shows, how the method `Response<ResponseBody> getWrappedExperiment(...)` is used in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `RxJava`. The solution for me was to wrap the Response inside `Observable/Single`:

```
@Headers("accept: */*")
@GET("experiment")
Single<Response<ResponseBody>> getWrappedExperiment(@Header("Authorization") @NonNull final String authenticationToken, @Query("active") @NonNull final Boolean isActive);
```

Then `flatMap` the result so you have access to the Response object itself.